# Flutter Web - Missing copy option in SelectableText Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to use the Flutter `SelectableText` Widget to make sure it is possible to copy the Text in my **web application**, but there is no 'copy' option appearing in the Context Menu.

[image: Context Menu]

I am using the following Code 
("select all" and "copy" should be given as default toolbar options https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText/toolbarOptions.html):

```
SelectableText(
  'Hello from Flutter',
),
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: try double click on the text in your simulator. It works with me

Comment: This will not work as of now. There is an open issue for this. Please follow it in flutter github [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47234)..

Comment: This seems ro be the possible workaround for now. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/55419#issuecomment-640988193

Comment: any solution for this other than work around?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this it's working but we can't select a part of the text but we can select whole.

```
child: SelectableText(sample.sourceCode,
          cursorColor: Colors.red,
          showCursor: true,
          toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
              copy: true,
              selectAll: true,
              cut: false,
              paste: false
          ),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal))
```

in web use `Ctrl` + `A` and `Ctrl` + `C` to copy the whole text.